# Change elements of array to a[i] = i recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```
public static void what(int[] arr, int i)
{
   if (i == 0) 
      return;
   arr[arr.length - i] = i;  
   i--; 
   what(arr, i); // recursive method call
}
```

What I have here doesn't change anything, the array stays the same and a[i] doesn't = i. My logic is way off, any help?

I did a previous code where I had to set elements in an int array to zero, clearing the array. I used that as a basis for this initialization as well.

Comment: Wait, so `i` is both your array index, *and* the value you're setting in your array?

Comment: How is it called? Not like `what(arr, 0)` by chance?

Comment: If you want `a[i] = i`, then you should probably set your index to `i` instead of `arr.length - i`.

Comment: Recursion is a rediculous technique to solve this.  Use a loop, for example `for (index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) arr[index] = index;`.  If this is homework, consider mentioning "this is homework, recursion is required"

Comment: What does the second parameter stands for? What is the purpose of your function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a[i] = i then change to this:

```
public static void what(int[] arr, int i)
  {

   if (i == 0) 
      return;
   arr[arr.length - i] = arr.length - i;  
   i--; 
   what(arr, i); // recursive method call

}
```

Comment: do we really need the index calculation operation ? we can direcly use i there , rt?

Comment: well depends on whether i matters, for example {1,1,1,1,1} is the array you call what(arr,2) you get arr = {1,1,1,3,4}. Other wise why even pass i when you can use length

Comment: What is the sample input/output of your program. The input/output you quoted is wrong.He wants all a[i] to be i The same can be achieved without the calculation you have

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling the function like `what(array,array.length)`:

```
public static void what(int[] arr, int i)
{
   if ( i == 0 ) 
      return;
   arr[i] = i;  
   what(arr, i-1); // recursive method call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need ?

```
 public static void what (int[] arr, int i)
{

    if (i == 0)
        return;
    arr[i-1] = i-1;
    i--;
    what(arr, i); // recursive method call

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it is more readable, easier to understand if you do it the other way, starting from the front.

```
private static void what( int[] arr, int i )
{
    if( i >= arr.length )
        return;    
    arr[i] = i;
    what( arr, i + 1 );
}
```

[Here is it running](http://ideone.com/EdncLP).

Answer (score 0):

This method will always return an array of the following content.

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1};
```

Your input array may be something like this. That may be the reason of your results not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is pointless in this case because you will need more code, including a cycle, to validate the second parameter rather to solve the task.

The best case scenario for `int[] intArr = new int[]{43,56,24,745,32}` is to call `what(intArr, 5)` and get `int[]{5,4,3,2,1}`

Ofcourse, we have the most obvious issue: `what(intArr,4343)` will lead us to `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but it can be fixed with ease: `if( i <= arr.length && i>0 )`.

It will be much more interesting if we will pass random value between 0 and 5(`intArr.length`)

`what(intArr,2)` will result in `int[]{43, 56, 24, 2, 1}`. How will you handle this case? The only way I see is to loop through `intArr` from `i+1` to `intArr.length-1` and check if we already performed `what(intArr,3)`, `what(intArr,4)` and `what(intArr,5)`.

Each time you call your method, you will need to loop through i-1 elements and check if it was processed already.

I would prefer to use a regular function with a loop:

```
public static void what(int[] arr)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
           arr[i] = arr.length-i;
       }
    }
```